# Recursive function - safety net using step counter

Tags: php, recursion

when implementing a recursive function during development, i will use a counter and exit if it reaches a certain limit so as not to crash if i make a mistake.

Question: should i keep this in place moving in to production, or should the code be tested so well, that there should be no need for this.

The function in question is a recursive function generating a sitemap.  Iterating over a set of nodes which all can have children.

Comment: Don't put broken code into production. That's about all I can offer.

Comment: Im not advocating putting broken code into production.  I am asking, should the code be tested to a point where there is absolutely no way at all that the recursive function could fail and cause the system to crash.  Therefore keeping this safety code in place should not be necessary

Comment: what code? what does it do? to little detail for a real question

Comment: @Dagon - i have edited the question to say what the function does, though i feel that this would apply to recursive functions in general.  Should a recursive function go wrong then it could cause an infinite loop and that is what the safetly code is gaurding against

Comment: @JMoore very little anything applies to every case, its why the faq suggests every good question includes code. http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't test everything 100%, but you should test as much as reasonably possible. Look into unit testing, it's generally a very simple procedure and will help eliminate the majority of bugs.